# Why can't I run any Android NDK commands?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, android

I had been running Mint 12 before, and everything was working there. I switched to Ubuntu 12.04, and now I am very frustrated.

When I run `ndk-build`, I get

```
/home/buzz/ndk/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/make: not found
```

So, I changed to that folder directly. When I type in `./make`, I get

```
bash: ./make: No such file or directory
```

Typing `ls` clearly shows the file where I am! I did some hacking around (pointing to external tools) to get past each error (just to experiment), and I ran into this!

```
/home/buzz/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found
```

Why? Why are all these files unable to be found? As I said above, this was all working just fine in another distro. What changed? What's extra frustrating is that if I push TAB to auto-complete, it *works*. So, the file is clearly there (and clearly marked with execution permissions). So, why can't it be found?

Comment: Did you try `sudo ndk-build`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.

I installed `ia32-libs`, and everything started working. It's bizarre that running an executable of the wrong architecture results in "command not found". I was trying all the wrong things.

Answer (score 4):

Probably would have been enough to install the *i386* variant of `libgcc1`.

Comment: +1: This worked for me under Ubuntu 12.04 and you make an excellent point about ia32-libs being removed in Ubuntu 12.10.